# How to animate an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

Here is my code which I apply to each object at each iteration for my animation:

```
for(var i=0;i<60;i++){
 var ship = new object();
        ship.size = 10;
        ship.image = getMediaObject('shipImage');
        ship.speed.x = 0;
        ship.speed.y = 0;
        ship.flyingByEllipce = true;
        ship.MoveEllipce(p, cont, 4, 100);
        shipsMove.push(clone(ship));
}
for (var i = 0; i < shipsMove.length / 2; i++) {
    shipsMove[i].speed.x = (p1.info.point.x - shipsMove[i].x) / sens;
    shipsMove[i].speed.y = (p1.info.point.y - shipsMove[i].y) / sens;
    p.pop--;
    currentPop--;
    document.getElementById('population-current').innerHTML = currentPop;
    shipsMove[i].animatable = true;
    shipsMove[i].flyingByEllipce = false;
    shipsMove[i].animate(cont, p1.x + 25, p1.y + 25);
    shipsMove[i].animate(shipGo, p1.x + 25, p1.y + 25);
}
```

And here is the code for animation itself:

```
function object() { //flying object
var Ship = this;
this.x = 0;
this.y = 0;
this.speed={ x: 0, y: 0 };
this.size = 20;
this.iter = 0;
this.health = 100;
this.position = 3;
this.print= function (canvas) {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this.image, (this.x - this.size), (this.y - this.size), this.size, this.size);
};
this.redraw = function (canvas, beforeX, beforeY, afterX, afterY) {
    var params = {
        fromX: (beforeX - this.size),
        fromY: (beforeY - this.size),
        size: (this.size * 3),
        toX: (afterX - this.size),
        toY: (afterY - this.size)
    }
    canvas.ctx.clearRect(params.fromX - 7, params.fromY - 7, params.size + 2, params.size + 2);
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(getMediaObject('shipImage'), params.toX, params.toY, this.size, this.size);
};
this.animatable = false;
//метод подсчета урона наносимого кораблями
this.battle = function (canv,damage) {
    this.health -= damage;
    if (this.health <= 0)
        canv.ctx.clearRect((this.x - this.size) - 1, (this.y - this.size) - 1, (this.size) + 3, (this.size) + 3);
}
//анимация полета корабля
this.animate = function (canvas, tox, toy) {
    if ((this.x + this.speed.x) >= (tox - this.size) && (this.y + this.speed.y) <= (toy - this.size)) {
        //canvas.ctx.clearRect((Ship.x - Ship.size) - 1, (Ship.y - Ship.size) - 1, (Ship.size) + 3, (Ship.size) + 3);
        this.animatable = false;
    } else if ((this.x + this.speed.x) >= (tox - this.size) && (this.y + this.speed.y) >= (toy - this.size)) {
        //canvas.ctx.clearRect((Ship.x - Ship.size) - 1, (Ship.y - Ship.size) - 1, (Ship.size) + 3, (Ship.size) + 3);
        this.animatable = false;
    }
    this.redraw(canvas, this.x, this.y, (this.x + this.speed.x), (this.y + this.speed.y));
    this.x += this.speed.x;
    this.y += this.speed.y;
    if (this.animatable == true) {
        this.tim = setTimeout(this.animate, 60, canvas, tox, toy);
    } else clearTimeout(this.tim);
};
```

When I apply an animation to a single object, then it works, but when I need to apply animation to multiple objects, it does not happen, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `Ship` in the second block? Can you post *all* of your code?

Comment: please post a full jsfiddle example

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need to replace `Ship` with `this` in your method.

Comment: No they aren't. Since you don't execute `var Ship = this;` line in your loop, `Ship` keeps referring to some particular instance, not the current one as `this` always does.

Comment: Replaced `Ship` on `this` and now the animation is a step and stops, and so each click.

Comment: You need to introduce a closure to keep `this` reference in the `setTimeout` line: instead of `this.animate` write `function() { thisShip.animate(); }` and add `var thisShip = this;` right before `setTimeout` line.